# Accessing DOM within template scope - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am quite new to Angular JS and I am in a situation where I need to select some DOM elements within my directive template (I know DOM manipulation is frowned upon in Angular, but in my situation I don't really see much way around it without a lot of time put in…). The problem is that I use my directive more than once.

Here is a code example to clarify what I mean:

My index.html:

```
<html>
  <head> <! necessary script> </head>
  <body ng-app='foo'>
    <my-directive my-attr="someVal"></my-directive>
    <my-directive my-attr="otherVal"></my-directive>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module('foo',[]).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'foo-template.html',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
      //jQuery selector
      scope.bar = angular.element($('.bar').first());
      scope.bar.someFunction(attrs.myAttr);

      function someFunction(message) {
        scope.bar.html(message);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

My template (foo-template.html):

```
<p class='bar'></p>
```

So after injection my index.html would look something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class='bar'>otherVal</p>
    <p class='bar'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I want it to be:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class='bar'>someVal</p>
    <p class='bar'>otherVal</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to limit my access to within the template currently being controlled, since the second time I use my directive it reaches up to the first paragraph and updates it.
I thought that using an isolate scope would solve the problem, but it does not.

Does anybody know how to achieve this (or have any tips on how to refactor my code so that I do not have to select DOM elements)? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the reference for each element specified in your directive link function: elem.

```
angular.module('foo',[]).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'foo-template.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function(elem, attrs) {
      elem.html(attrs.myAttr);
    }
  };
});
```

The element reference is already encased in `angular.element` so you should be able to use those functions on it. If you need a direct DOM reference, use `elem[0]` instead.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I guess I got the impression that angular.element was the same as $element… but they don't seem to work the same way. What is the difference?

Comment: That's a really good question. I've never used $element, but from what I can find they are supposed to be the same. Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your example is WAY more simple than whatever you are doing, I think you are just approaching it the wrong way.  You could just as easily do:

Template:

```
<p class='bar'>{{message}}</p>
```

JS:

```
link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
  scope.message = attrs.myAttr;
}
```

Comment: It is much simpler. I think my main problem is that I learned Angular quickly, designed the layout quickly, and got stuck now that it is too big for me to change. Thank anyways!